How to send files from one computer to another in Spring Boot
I'm working on a Spring Boot project where I can send messages through the chat. But the other part is to send files like how you would in iMessages, WhatsApp, etc. My question is how can I send files from one computer to another? I'm able to send messages through two computers already.
I've read into Multipart file upload but that didn't explain how to do it between two computers. I know I can technically have the server send the file to a database/cloud, but I would like to know how to send it directly between each other? Ex: I send file from client, then the server receives it and sends it to client 2 which can then download the file.
Any tips or things I should look into would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

The best approach is to upload the file from client 1 and store it on the Spring Boot server. Then, client 2 can request a download and retrieve it from the server as well.

How can I store it on the spring boot server? I read into it and didn’t find anything other than the Multipart file?  Thanks for clarifying this concept. It made it more clear how it works

You should upload it and store it on the filesystem of your spring boot server. You can find resource on official spring documentation https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files
